# Migration strategy to migrate a DHCP scope from old DHCP server to new DHCP server as smooth as possible

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

My current homeLab and entire home is currently running on a single subnet 192.168.0.0/24 with my ISP provided router running a DHCP scope handing out addresses in the 192.168.0.20-192.168.0.254 range, and a number of hosts with static IP addresses in the 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.15 range. I want to move the DHCP service to a freshly installed ISC-DCP-Server installed on an Ubuntu server, to get more control and proper integration between DHCP and DNS.
I have installed and configured but not yet started the ISC-DHCP Server, so the ISP router is still responsible for handing out IP-adresses in the dynamic range. I was hoping, that someone could give any advice, tips, pointers for making the transition of the DHCP scope to the new server as smooth as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Turn off the DHCP service on the router.
2. Start the DHCP service on your new DHCP server.

When the DHCP clients enter the rebinding phase they'll get their ip address configuration from the new DHCP server.